# Obtaining Google account token from GoogleApiClient without GET_ACCOUNTS permission

Tags: android, google-plus, google-play-services, google-signin

This is traditional way to obtain token from GoogleApiClient used in Google+ login:

```
String token = GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(apiClient.getContext(), getAccountNameFromGoogle(apiClient), SCOPE);
```

However, `GetAccountNameFromGoogle` method requires `android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS` permission and in Android M Developer Preview 3, this permission is now  marked as dangerous and grouped into contacts group. That means that if someone wants to login into my app he needs need to grant my app full contacts permissions which is a bit overkill.

Is there a way to achieve this without `GET_ACCOUNTS` permission?

One potential answer I found is obtaining account name from [AccountPicker](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/AccountPicker), but that forces user to pick his account it twice (once for Google Plus authentication and once for AccountPicker) which is also not very friendly solution.

Comment: I tried to use the G+ signin button [here](https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/tree/master/android/signin) and successful signin without using `android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS` permission. I found that it works on Lollipop and has a problem on M preview 3 when running to `Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient).getDisplayName();`, it will get null pointer. I have report the issue [here](https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/issues/25).

Comment: Yes, I'm already using that sign in. However that only allows you to use APIs inside play services. If you want to forward token to the server or use on another APIs outside play services, you need to retrieve the token.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is how I eventually solved it:

I ditched `GoogleApiClient` completely and switched to [AccountPicker](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/AccountPicker.html). It is not perfect, but I can still use all features of `GoogleApiClient`, albeit not that effortlessly.

Google's guide to this: https://developers.google.com/android/guides/http-auth

Comment: How did you get user information like name and other information from google plus without using googleApiClient?

Comment: @VihaanVerma After I got token, I could use Google+ REST api with that token to retrieve all info.